# Case statement error message in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

Hello can somebody help me with something thats been bugging me for a while. I have a simple case statement and to the best of my knowledge the syntax is good. see the below code

```
LIBRARY IEEE;
USE IEEE.std_logic_1164.all;

ENTITY D7SEGSEL IS
    PORT (
            SW      :in std_logic_vector(3 DOWNTO 0);
            SEG :out std_logic_vector(6 DOWNTO 0)
            );
END ENTITY D7SEGSEL;

ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF D7SEGSEL IS      
BEGIN
    CASE SW IS
        WHEN "1000000" => SEG <= "0000";
              "1111001" => SEG <= "0001";
              "0100100" => SEG <= "0010";
              "0110000" => SEG <= "0011";
              "0011001" => SEG <= "0100";
              "0010010" => SEG <= "0101";
              "0000010" => SEG <= "0110";
              "1111000" => SEG <= "0111";
              "0000000" => SEG <= "1000";
              "0011000" => SEG <= "1001";
              "0001000" => SEG <= "1010";
              "0000011" => SEG <= "1011";
              "1000110" => SEG <= "1100";
              "0100001" => SEG <= "1101";
              "0000110" => SEG <= "1110";
              "0001110" => SEG <= "1111";
        END CASE;
END ARCHITECTURE behavioral;
```

its for a simple 7SEG LED driver, each time i compile the code though I get the following **error messages:**

> Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at D7SEGCASE.vhd(19) near text
>   "CASE";  expecting "end", or "(", or an identifier ("case" is a
>   reserved keyword), or a concurrent statement
>   Error (10500): VHDL syntax error at D7SEGCASE.vhd(21) near text "=>";  expecting > "(", or
>   "'", or "."

Can anyone point out the obvious in what I'm doing wrong

I have already made a decoder for the 7seg with a select/when statement but want to practice the use of case and then make it synchronous with the addition of a clock input

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few problems.

1. You are missing your process statement.
2. You are missing subsequent "when" after your first condition.
3. You have reversed your condition and your assignment in your WHEN conditions.

See fixes below:

```
ARCHITECTURE behavioral OF D7SEGSEL IS      
BEGIN
    my_case : process(sw, seg)
    begin
        CASE SW IS
            WHEN "0000" => SEG <= "1000000";
            WHEN "0001" => SEG <= "1111001";
            -- Other Assignments follow...
        END CASE;
    end process my_case;
END ARCHITECTURE behavioral;
```

Comment: Thanks for the feed back really appreciate it :)

Answer (score 2):

As pointed out by others, there are some problems with your code, but luckily there are different options to implement what you want.

**Case (process)**

```
process (SW) is
begin
  case SW is
    when "0000" => SEG <= "1000000";
    when "0001" => SEG <= "1111001";
    when "0010" => SEG <= "0100100";
    when "0011" => SEG <= "0110000";
    when "0100" => SEG <= "0011001";
    when "0101" => SEG <= "0010010";
    when "0110" => SEG <= "0000010";
    when "0111" => SEG <= "1111000";
    when "1000" => SEG <= "0000000";
    when "1001" => SEG <= "0011000";
    when "1010" => SEG <= "0001000";
    when "1011" => SEG <= "0000011";
    when "1100" => SEG <= "1000110";
    when "1101" => SEG <= "0100001";
    when "1110" => SEG <= "0000110";
    when "1111" => SEG <= "0001110";
    when others => SEG <= (others => 'X');
  end case;
end process;
```

**When (concurrent)**

```
SEG <= "1000000" when SW = "0000" else
       "1111001" when SW = "0001" else
       "0100100" when SW = "0010" else
       "0110000" when SW = "0011" else
       "0011001" when SW = "0100" else
       "0010010" when SW = "0101" else
       "0000010" when SW = "0110" else
       "1111000" when SW = "0111" else
       "0000000" when SW = "1000" else
       "0011000" when SW = "1001" else
       "0001000" when SW = "1010" else
       "0000011" when SW = "1011" else
       "1000110" when SW = "1100" else
       "0100001" when SW = "1101" else
       "0000110" when SW = "1110" else
       "0001110" when SW = "1111" else
       (others => 'X');
```

**Select (concurrent)**

```
d7seg : with SW select
  SEG <= "1000000" when "0000",
         "1111001" when "0001",
         "0100100" when "0010",
         "0110000" when "0011",
         "0011001" when "0100",
         "0010010" when "0101",
         "0000010" when "0110",
         "1111000" when "0111",
         "0000000" when "1000",
         "0011000" when "1001",
         "0001000" when "1010",
         "0000011" when "1011",
         "1000110" when "1100",
         "0100001" when "1101",
         "0000110" when "1110",
         "0001110" when "1111",
         (others => 'X') when others;
```

The Select (concurrent) is compact and with few repetitions, and is likely to yield a small implementation, so will be a good choice.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see process in your code.

```
process(sw,seg)
.
.
.
end process
```

check if you get after adding it